# how get name from call log android

Tags: android, calllog

```
Cursor managedCursor = getContentResolver().query(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, android.provider.CallLog.Calls.TYPE + "=" + android.provider.CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE, null, null);
        //Cursor managedCursor = managedQuery(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
        int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
        int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
        int duration = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
        int name = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME);
```

Comment: How ask here. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score -1):

In your code you got the column number of the fields then you have to retrive data from that using cursor.Firstly intilize cursor to move to first then repeat the loop till it reached the last .Hoping the following code will works.

```
      callogcursor.moveToFirst();//calog cursor means your managed cursor
        do
        {
       phNumber = callogcursor.getString(number);
       phName = callogcursor.getString(name)+"  ";
       callType = callogcursor.getString(type);





      }while (callogcursor.moveToNext());
```